# Why addition using bitwise operators in this code very slower than arithmetic addition

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, compiler-optimization

I tried comparing arithmetic addition with a function using bitwise operations i wrote - to find that the latter was almost `10x` slower. What could be the reason for such disparity in speed? Since i am adding to the same number in the loop, does the compiler rewrite it to something more optimal in the first case?

**Using arithmetic operation:**

```
int main()
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    int x;
    int i = 1000000000;
    while(i--) {
    x = 1147483000 + i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", x);

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("time spent = %f\n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1147483000
time spent = 3.520000
```

**Using bitwise operators:**

The line inside `while loop` was replaced with:

```
x = add(1147483000, i);
```

and here's the `add` function:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    while(y != 0) {
        int carry = (x & y);
        x = x ^ y;
        y = carry << 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Output:

```
1147483000
time spent = 32.940000
```

Comment: Are you sure that this extra time is not the one required for a function call (overhead). I have read about those somewhere. Try putting your add function block into the code and see if it gives much difference in run time. Also try seeing the assembly code generated by both methods.

Comment: @CrystalMeth If a function call here causes an additional 29 seconds, you have bigger problems to worry about.

Comment: @hvd : What I am trying to say is that the function call may be one of the factors responsible for the extra time. I did not say that it was the only reason.

Comment: You are replacing a single instruction by a loop of three instructions and you are surprised it is slower?

Comment: @CrystalMeth i put the function block in the code - no difference. I'm not very adept at assembly.

Comment: @Marian surprised it's `10x` slower !!

Comment: @CrystalMeth Okay, that's fair enough. I expect it to be irrelevant, though.

Comment: BTW: At the end of your loop `x` always equals to `1147483000` and `i` to `-1`. A good compiler would remove the loop completely.

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan I'd be surprised it's only 10x slower for a function that may be more than 100x slower. Each loop you have comparison, jump, and, xor, shift which result in 4 or 5 instructions depending on architectures. For the worst case it'll loop 32 times or 128-160 instructions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integer arithmetic is performed in hardware typically in a very small number of clock cycles.

You will not be able to get close to this performance in software. Your implementation using bitwise operations involves a function call and a loop. The bitwise operations that you perform typically cost similar numbers of clock cycles as arithmetic.

You are performing three bitwise operations per iteration. Frankly, I'm astonished that there is only a factor of 10 here.

I also wonder what your compiler settings are, specifically any optimizations. A good compiler could eliminate your while loop in the arithmetic version. For performance comparisons you should be comparing optimised code. It looks as if you might not be doing so.

It's difficult to know what you are trying to achieve here, but do not expect to beat the performance of hardware arithmetic units.

Comment: Arithmetic operations are compiled to dedicated arithmetic op codes. The CPU has arithmetic units that can perform arithmetic faster than any software can.

Comment: CPUs have hardware adders that do all the work in one instruction, probably in 1 or a few clocks depending on hardware. Your software adder do one loop for a bit and loop for the number of bits in y. Since one loop needs at least 3 instructions (not counting loop overhead), your adder runs may run slower nearly 100x in worse case (32 loops x 3 instruction/loop). Unroll your loop to reduce loop overhead and you'll see the difference

Answer (score 5):

You have replaced this:

```
x = 1147483000 + i;
```

with this:

```
while(y != 0) {
    int carry = (x & y);
    x = x ^ y;
    y = carry << 1;
}
```

Of course you get a huge slow-down! `+` of two integers is one assembly instruction. Your `while` loop executes many instructions, effectively simulating in software what the hardware does when it executes an addition.

---

To elaborate more, this is how a [full adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_adder#Full_adder) looks like. With 32-bit addition, the [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) contains 32 of this unit cascaded. Each of those hardware elements have very very small delay. The delay of the wires is negligible. So if the software adds two 32-bit numbers together, it takes very very little time.

On the other hand, if you try to simulate the addition by hand, you make the CPU go to memory, fetch and decode some instructions 32 times which takes considerably longer time.

[image]

Comment: Also, the overhead of calling a function 1 million times. Compiler might optimize it out with some automatic inlining with different settings such as -O3.  But it won't get rid of the overhead of completely.

Comment: @selbie, I'm sure reimplementing addition as a software loop has the major impact. One can of course test by simply by making the function inline and test again.

Comment: in fact modern CPUs usually use much more complex adders since a series of full adders require the number of clocks proportional to the number of bits. 32-bit adders require 32 clocks

Answer (score 1):

When you replace addition with a function call:
calling the function is more time intensive than simple addition because function call is associated with stack operations.

In the function you are replacing addition with three bitwise operations - how fast they are compared to addition may be an issue- though not confirm about that without testing. Can you post the individual times for the three bitwise operations here?:

1.

```
//tic
while(i--) {
    int carry = (x & y);
}
//toc
```

2.

```
//tic
while(i--) {
    x = x ^ y;
}
//toc
```

3.

```
//tic
while(i--) {
    y = carry << 1;
}
//toc
```

But function call should be the main reason.